# How to do zonal statistics for large size rasters in Python?

Tags: python, memory, raster, large-data, rasterstats

My goal is to do zonal statistics for hundreds of rasters using the same shaplefile and save the results as a csv file. I have wrote a code and it works fine for small size test shaplefile but not my real project.

Here is the code I am using.

```
##### This code now works for small but not large size problem

import rasterio
import geopandas as gpd
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
from rasterstats import gen_zonal_stats
import pandas as pd
import glob

# Open the shapefile
polygons = gpd.read_file('/test/LargeDomainBoundary.shp')

# List of rasters to process
# Get a list of all raster files in a directory
raster_list = glob.glob('/test1/*.tif')
print(raster_list)

# Creating an empty dataframe to store the results
results_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop through the rasters
for raster_path in raster_list:

    # Open the raster file
    with rasterio.open(raster_path) as src:
      raster = src.read(1)
      print(raster.shape)
      trans = src.transform # --> here do src.transform instead of src.affine
      print(trans)

    # Perform zonal statistics
    stats = zonal_stats(polygons, raster, stats=['mean', 'sum', 'min', 'count', 'max'], affine=trans, tolerance=0.1, nodata=-32768) #nodata=-9999
#     stats = list(
#         gen_zonal_stats(polygons, raster, affine=trans, stats=['mean', 'sum', 'min', 'count', 'max'], nodata=-32768,
#                         block_size=(1000, 1000)))


    # Creating a dataframe from the stats
    df = pd.DataFrame(stats)
    # Adding the name of the raster processed as a column
    df["Raster"] = raster_path
    # Concatenating the result to the results dataframe
    results_df = pd.concat([results_df, df])

# Saving the results to a CSV file
results_df.to_csv('/globalhome/test/zonal_stats_results.csv', index=False)
```

I am using zonal_stats of rasterstats to do the job. I also tried gen_zonal_stats, which can set the block_size so the raster can be processed in smaller chunks. However, even 100*100 block size won't solve the problem. My rasters size is (13665, 30641) and I got the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\GDAL\zonalusingsameshapefile.py", line 32, in 
stats = list(
File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\venvgdal\lib\site-packages\rasterstats\main.py", line 155, in gen_zonal_stats
fsrc = rast.read(bounds=geom_bounds)
File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\venvgdal\lib\site-packages\rasterstats\io.py", line 298, in read
new_array = boundless_array(
File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\venvgdal\lib\site-packages\rasterstats\io.py", line 179, in boundless_array
out = np.ones(shape=window_shape) * nodata
File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\venvgdal\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 204, in ones
a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

Process finished with exit code 1